# Define variable before while loop or as static in loop

Tags: c, while-loop, static, variable-declaration, flash-memory

I am programming a microcontroller (PIC18, 8 bit) in C99. I have this piece of code: a timeout, that returns early if triggered:

```
uint16_t timeout_x100us = 50000;

while (!is_interruptflag())                 // When this interrupt occurs, continue.
{
    if (!(--timeout_x100us))                // Decrement and check timer.
    {
        return;                             // Timeout ran out.
    }

    __delay_us(100);                        // Delay for 100µs.
}
```

**I have two questions: (1)** Is it good practice/does it make sense to define the variable `timeout_x100us` as static inside the loop to minimize its scope?

```
while (!is_interruptflag())                 // When this interrupt occurs, continue.
{
    static uint16_t timeout_x100us = 50000;

    if (!(--timeout_x100us))                // Decrement and check timer.
    {
        return;                             // Timeout ran out.
    }

    __delay_us(100);                        // Delay for 100µs.
}
```

**(2)** I am also trying to minimize program memory usage. The first code snippet uses 36 bytes of memory, whereas the second one (static) uses 54 bytes, which is significantly more (no compiler optimizations). Why does the static declaration use more program memory? Thank you.

Comment: What it does not make sense is to have a codition that breaks the `while` loop where the `while` construct has its own condition..... Moreover the second solution does not work as you want...

Comment: What does the generated assembly look like for the two examples? That is the starting point to understand the difference. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @LPs: Why not? If the while condition is false, the wait for the flag is over and the code continues. However if the timeout runs out, the function is terminated completely. Do you see a different approach?

Comment: @Gerhard: I check the listing files, in the static version no code for the definition is generated (now obviously :) ), but somewhere else in the file. Apparently this takes more instructions. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) Is it good practice/does it make sense to define the variable timeout_x100us as static inside the loop to minimize its scope?

Generally it is good practice to reduce scope of variables. Regardless of that, you need to set it to a value in run-time before it is used.

However, for embedded systems specifically, it is bad practice to write code that relies on static storage initialization (of .data/.bss). Partially because a very long time could have passed between initialization and variable use, partially because it is common to use non-standard start-up code in the CRT that *doesn't* even initialize such variables.

What you should do is to keep `timeout_x100us` as a local variable with automatic storage, then initialize it to a value before executing the code, each time.

Also replace the magic number `50000` with a meaningful named `#define`.

Also keep in mind that the integer constant `50000` is of type 32 bit `long` on PIC, which is potentially a performance-killing bug. Replace it with `50000u` to ensure 16 bit `unsigned int` instead.

You should be able to replace the code with something like this:

```
uint16_t i;
for(i=0; !is_interruptflag() && i<TIMEOUT; i++)
{
  __delay_us(100);
}

if(i==TIMEOUT)
{
  return ;
}
```

---

> (2) I am also trying to minimize program memory usage. The first code snippet uses 36 bytes of memory, whereas the second one (static) uses 54 bytes

The first uses the stack instead, so it simply uses a different kind of memory. The extra code bloat could be related to some PIC Harvard architecture hiccup. Disassemble and investigate why.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer, I learned something new. I am going to keep it in mind. Your code example is more readable than mine, I'm going to copy it.

Answer (score 2):

`static` in this case does not minimize the scope. It is right opposite - it makes it static storage variable and it lives as long as the application (same as global variables, taking the RAM memory). Only the C visibility is reduced.

BTW it will be initialized only once before the call to the main function.

Comment: @LPs pointless actually. And it wastes **forever** two bytes of memory (this memory is allocated globally)

Comment: I neglected the fact, that the definition for the static variable is not done inside the function... This made me believe it makes sense in terms of scope. Tanks for the clarification. As for the memory usage, see my answer to Gerhard.